# htaccess adding .php to the end of $_GET variables when adding slash

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I attempted to create a little bit of `htaccess` which alters a **URL** from something like

> http://localhost/website/page.php?id=_abc-123

to

> http://localhost/website/page/_abc-123

It works for the most part, in that I can visit the page without having trouble locating `scripts` and **CSS** files. However, if I try to echo out `$_GET["id"]`, instead of getting `_abc-123`, I will get `_abc-123.php`.

This is what I have so far within my **htaccess** file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# remove extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

# movie page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

All help is appreciated,

Thanks.

Comment: Don't use `mod-rewrite` to hide file extensions, that's what `MultiViews` is for. All that's happening is your first rewrite rule is matching the URL you want and redirecting to `page/_abc-123.php` which is then being picked up by your second rule

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test movie page first, and test if file with .php exists:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

# movie page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]

# remove extensions
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you are not sure where your error lies, you can try online tools for .htaccess like [htaccess.mwl.be](http://htaccess.mwl.be/).

Obviously your first RewriteRule contitions are met, which results in your "error".

With the help of this tool and some knowledge about how regex work, we can fix your .htaccess to this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

# remove extensions
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC]

# movie page
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^page/([^/]*)$ page.php?id=$1 [L]
```

The only thing I changed is removing the "L" flag from your first `RewriteRule`, because its RewriteCond is met but we need it to go through the second `RewriteRule`.

For more information about the L-flag have a look at the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_l).